# Trying to make virtual host in xampp on CENTOS 7

Tags: linux, apache, centos, xampp

I tried yesterday to make a virtual host.
i did few steps to make it:

1. - i removed the hash (#) in `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/` not its:

> (hash)Virtual hosts
>
> Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

2. - i edited the `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to this:
     [image: Vhosts file by SSH]
3. - i created directory for `pic.localhost` i  3 commands via root:

> mkdir /opt/lampp/pictures/
>
> chown daemon:daemon 770 -R /opt/lampp/pictures/
>
> chmod 770 -R /opt/lampp/pictures/

4. - i added this following lined to `/etc/hosts/` file:

   127.0.0.1               pic.localhost

i restarted the `xampp(version 5.6.8)` and its not working. what i did wrong?

log file `picture-access_log` shows:

> 5.29.203.187 - - [01/Jul/2015:18:04:07 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 1036

log file `picture-error_log` shows:

> [Wed Jul 01 18:04:07.173810 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 24261]
>   [client 5.29.203.187:57710] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: /opt/lampp/pictures/

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Anything at all?

Comment: I`m got no errors. the log files are empty

Comment: With no log files, then the server likely isn't even starting. You can strace the process and see what it's doing. May be overkill, but it will definitely tell you what's happening under the hood.

Comment: i edited the question with the log files at the end.

Comment: Return code 403 is Forbidden. Likely either a permission or selinux issue.